# django template replace url by template var

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there the possibility to dinamically replace a url call from a template?

in the **form** I insert:

```
{% include "mytemplate.html" with soggetto='gigi' %}
```

in the **template**

```
  url: '{% url 'go_to_this_{{soggetto}}' %}'
```

is there a way to replace the {{soggetto}} part dinamically or should I add a parameter to the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template filter:

```
{% url 'go_to_this_'|add:soggetto %}
```

However, it might be cleaner to include a `soggetto` parameter in the url, then you could do:

```
{% url 'go_to_this' soggetto %}
```